# How to refresh datatables with new data in Laravel vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

I am using datatables 1.10.19 in vue js. .How can I refresh the table after inserting new data into data base ? I used clear, destroy and draw but nothing works.Here is my entire code.
the data is not loaded in to datatable until the page is refreshed

```
 table() {    this.$nextTick(() => {
                        $('#sampleTable').DataTable();
                       })
                       },
                     get() {
                       axios.get('api/user').then(res => {
                        this.users = res.data
                        // console.log("after: " + this.users);
                        this.table()
                        });
                     axios.get("api/getRoles").then(({
                           data
                        }) => (this.roles = data));
                        // if (refreshIt == true) {
                            
                            // this.retable();
                        // } else {
                            
                           this.table();
                           
                        // }
        
                    $(".selectpicker").selectpicker();
                },
                  create() {
                                    // this.validation();
                    this.form.post('api/user').then(() => {
                            $("#addnew").modal("hide");
                            toast.fire({
                                icon: "success",
                                type: "success",
                                title: "Information Created Successfully!"
                            });
                             Fire.$emit("refreshPage");
                            this.form.reset();
                            
                        })
                        .catch(er => {
                            console.log(er);
                        });
                 created() {
                // we call the show function here to be executed
                        this.get();
                
                Fire.$on("refreshPage", () => {
              
                  this.get();
                
               
            });}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution I destroy the datable in the create function $('#sampleTable').DataTable().destroy(); and then create it back like below

```
  create() {

    this.form.post('api/user').then(() => {
    $("#addnew").modal("hide");
    toast.fire({
    icon: "success",
    type: "success",
    title: "Information Created Successfully!"
    });
    $('#sampleTable').DataTable().destroy();// here I destroyed the table 
    Fire.$emit("refreshPage");// here I recreated the table
    this.form.reset();
    })
    .catch(er => {
    console.log(er);
    });
},
```